# In what ways can this custom hook be more performant?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to institute a custom hook that detects if an area outside of a modal has been clicked and if so close the modal. I am finding that the hook gets called, a LOT in the devtools and I am wondering what obvious things i am missing from a performance perspective here, I tried replacing useEffect with useMemo but that renders the page useless after you open close the modal more than 4 times in a row, which is an edge case i know but still id rather understand why that is happening.

````
/**
 * Hook that handles outside click event of the passed refs
 *
 * @param refs array of refs
 * @param handler a handler function to be called when clicked outside
 */
export function useOutsideClick(
  ref: Array<RefObject<HTMLElement>>,
  handleOutsideClick: (e: Event) => void,
) {
  useMemo(() => {
    function handleClick(e: Event) {
      if (!ref.some(containsClick(e))) {
        handleOutsideClick(e);
      }
    }
    document.addEventListener('mousedown', handleClick);

    return function cleanup() {
      document.removeEventListener('mousedown', handleClick);
    };
  }, [ref]);
}```
````

Comment: That's because useMemo doesn't work the same way useEffect does. You can't return a cleanup from useMemo, the returned value is the memo. Why did you think that your function being called many times was an issue?

Comment: Unrelated (probably), but `if (!ref.some(containsClick(e))) {` looks suspicious. It's certainly *possible* to create a `containsClick` function that would work like that (by having it return a function), but it's not clear to me why you'd want to which makes me suspect it's unintentional...?

Comment: Well the rub of it is, that if i use a useEffect instead of a useMemo here, the modal does not close. Everything else remains the same from an implementation perspective.

Comment: Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).